# Saying "I could have been on time" when still you have some time before the appointment

Tags: subjunctive-mood, past-perfect

On a different website I asked which sentence is more proper:

> The game starts in 5 minutes. If I had taken that train, I could have been on time.

> The game starts in 5 minutes. If I had taken that train, I could be on time.

I got answers that the first sentence is more proper.

But here I wonder why I need to say the first one though "not being on time" is still not the past.

I understand this case, which is about the past:

> This morning I was late for the appointment.  If I had not been stuck in traffic, I could have been in time for it.

Why should I say that using "have + past participle" when it is not about the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice Question, +1, Nicely worded too !

While Past tense is generally for events which have already happened, Present tense is for events which are ongoing & future tense is for events yet to happen, there are "other situations" to consider.

Three such "other situations" are wishes & conditionals & hypothetical events.

Your Question concerns Hypothetical Events.

Here ( [ecenglish](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/wishes-and-hypothetical-situations) ) are some guidelines to use in these cases :

> **Hypothetical situations**
> We use past tense forms to talk about a future that is not likely to happen:
>
> > What if you lost your job? How would you live?
> > They didn’t take a map! Suppose they got lost.
>
> We use **would and could** for hypothetical situations in the future :
>
> > I don’t think I’d like Canada. I’d hate the weather.
> > John’s coming to visit. He could stay with us. A hotel would be too expensive.

In your case, you can not change the Past, hence it is some Imaginary or Hypothetical situation in the future where, "If you **had** taken the train [ in the Past ], you **could/would/might have** made it on time [ in the future ]" ....

Here ( [britishcouncil](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/wishes-and-hypotheses) ) are similar guidelines :

> We use expressions [ like "in case" or "suppose" or "if" ] .... with past tense forms to talk about the present or future to suggest something is not likely to be true or to happen
>
> We use **modals would and could** for a hypothesis about the present or future
>
> We use **would** in the main clause and the past tense in a subordinate clause for a hypothesis about the present or future